# Does strapi have default database tables?

Tags: content-management-system, strapi

I am trying to run a select query via `entityService` in strapi from table called `files` but it gives me the `TypeError: Cannot destructure property 'kind' of 'strapi.getModel(...)' as it is undefined.` error. Looks like a model aka content-types schema is needed but when trying to create one I get error saying that the table already exists. But I could not find any table's fields' mention in the codebase. This seems like a blackbox for me. Can anyone help to explain(solve) my issue ?